# IOException - file being used by another process with FileShare.ReadWrite

Tags: c#, ioexception

I have been searching for a solution for my problem, tried out many possibility, but I still could not read a file content when it was being used by another process. I hope somebody can help:)

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(file)) //Here I try to simulate that the file is opened for read.
        {
            Assert.NotNull(xmlUtility.Load(file));
        }
```

And here is the code how I want to open it for read access:

```
        using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(fs);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using `OpenWrite` to simulate a read ? Because OpenWrite is denying all access from other processes : [check the remarks section in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Hm so basically this File.OpenWrite(file) opens the file with FileAccess.None, it means that I would not be able to open it from any other applicaiton / code right?

Comment: exactly. there might be a way around it, but you'd need the second application to run with more privileges, and possibly use another API to open the file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the root cause was that my simulation of the file being opened. That call "File.OpenWrite()" opens the file with FileAccess.None which disable the other access to the file.

Thanks to Sidewinder94:)

If I use other approach to simulate the file open then the given example works as well.

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to open It with notepad...word?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default)) {
// read the stream
}
```